# Como lograr agarrar la informacion de un tasklist

Tags: python-3.x

quisiera saber como puedo lograr para que la funcion tasklist del subprocess se compare con un input del usuario que en este caso seria la cantidad de "kbs" usados por el programa y comparar 1 por 1 de los programas y dar en el output

```
    import subprocess

usuario_informacion = int(input('Ingrese una cantidad de memoria en KB: '))
p = subprocess.run("tasklist", capture_output=True, encoding="cp850")
resultado = p.stdout.strip()
lineas = resultado.split("\n")


# TODO: bucle sobre las lineas
```

Quisiera saber como hacer para recorrer linea por linea que se guarde el nombre del proceso y la cantidad de kbs que utiliza y compararlas con el input del usuario